# How to recover articles after plugin error (IssueM)?

Tags: wordpress

I had an issue with the IssueM plugin recently where it was causing some back-end error and Wordpress automatically deactivated it along with IssueM's Issue to PDF. I updated via recovery mode and disabled Issue to PDF (which isn't needed anyway and seems to be the source of the issue) and the back end is now working fine. HOWEVER, none of the articles seem to exist anymore when you visit the page. From within Wordpress admin they are all there and seem to be correct as best as I can tell. On the site the titles all show up, but when you click on any (or try to preview any) it gives a not found error.

My best guess is that because IssueM uses articles and wordpress base doesn't that when it got deactivated and reactived something sort of disconnected?

I've already tried repairing the database via /wp-admin/maint/repair.php and it doesn't help (or find any errors).

**TL;DR: All articles are unable to be found on site front end after plugin (IssueM) error, deactivation, update, and reactivation.**

Edit: More info: It also looks like past issues are unavailable. Issues is also IssueM specific, so there's that. I tried creating a test article. Interestingly, before I published I was able to preview and everything looked fine. After I published it gave me the same "This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?" message as the other articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! Posting this here in case it helps someone in the future.

Apparently the permalink structure got messed up. I went to Settings > Permalinks and discovered that a custom structure was set, though strangely it wasn't even a valid structure. I changed that to `/%postname%/` and it all worked!